# Parse data with symbols using fscanf

Tags: c

I'm trying to insert separator for my input when storing if to a file but I'm getting error. When I try to insert with space, it seems ok. But with no space, still error.

Here's my code with space for storing input student.name and student.pass:

```
fprintf(fp, "%s %s\n", student.name, student.pass);
fclose(fp);
```

and when I check it:

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s", &student.name, &student.pass) != EOF)
{
    printf("Username is %s : Password is %s\n", student.name, student.pass);
    if(strcmp(student.name, a)==0)
    {
        printf("Exists");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not Exists");
    }
}
```

**the output:**

```
name: name;
pass: pass;
Username is name : Password is pass;
```

Working fine with space, but I need separator because when I try to input:

```
name: my name;
pass: pass;
Username is my : Password is pass;
Username is name : Password is pass;
```

How do I fix this with separator using '|' as separator, I prefer if the input will be like this:

```
fprintf(fp, "%s|%s\n", student.name, student.pass);
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: The `scanf` family of functions do simple pattern matching. The space matches all white-space. If you have another separator, you need to ask `scanf` to match that.

Comment: If you want to scan up until a newline,  use `getline`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm using fopen not a stream, can we use getline for fopen?

Comment: [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) is gnu specific, there is always the standard [std::fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets), but writing a `getchar()` loop with `realloc` is also simple.

Comment: @KamilCuk No not GNU specific, but POSIX specific.

Comment: Oh and `"%s"` reads *space delimited* strings. If there's no space between the string you want to read and the separator, then `"%s"` will make `scanf` to be greedy and read the separator as part of the string.

Comment: If you are going to use C++, why not use std::ifstream and std::ofstream?

Comment: sorry for the cout, and please i dont want to use stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%s` reads data until white character is encountered. So your data can't use space if you are using such data format.

One way to fix it is to update data format and use advanced format string (C style code):

```
int StudentWrite(FILE *f, Student *student) {
    return 2 == fprintf(f, "%s\n%s\n", student->name, student->pass);
}

int StudentRead(FILE *f, Student *student) {
    return 2 == fscanf(f, "%[^\n]%*c%[^\n]%*c", student->name, student->pass);
}
```

Where this format string works like this:

- `%[^\n]` read all characters, until end line `\n`
- `%*c` read single character and discard it. Since previous format reads all but not end line character, end line character is read and discarded.

To protect data from buffer overflow scanning format string can look like this: `%80[^\n]%*c%80[^\n]%*c` where `80` indicates capacity of target like `student->name` (remembered that you have to count terminating zero, so actual size of buffer must be by one greater then this value).

Comment: thanks it helps error on username with space, but would like to output the file is like this name|pass\n and not name\npass\n

Comment: so what is the problem to update format string? `"%[^|]%*c%[^\n]%*c"` and done.